# How to find max in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a table.

```
ID     |department_ID|mod_date
---------------------------------
 A     | 33          | 12/03/2014
 A     | 44          | 23/04/2015
 A     | 55          | 20/05/2016
 B     | 44          | 26/01/2014
 B     | 33          | 24/02/2015
 B     | 12          | 24/12/2015
 B     | 55          | 12/02/2016
 C     | 13          | 22/05/2014
 C     | 14          | 01/05/2015
 C     | 55          | 02/07/2016
 C     | 14          | 03/08/2016
 C     | 55          | 05/10/2016
```

From this table we need to extract those ID where department_id is `55` but was changed after 12/10/15 to anything other than `55`.

Please help with the query as I need to do this for huge amount of data.

Comment: what was changed and what action u need to make?

Comment: there should be a tracking of previous dept ID so we can identify if the previous value is 55 or  not

Comment: Give a sample output based on your sample input as well as what query you have tried so far and explain how it does not give the results you expect

Comment: Present department id should be 55 but should have changed from any other department id to 55 after 12/10/2015.

Comment: The result ID would be A and B but not C. As department ID for A and B was changed after 12/10/15 to many other department ids but not to 55 and at present it is 55. but for C, departments changed to 55 and then to 14 and then again to 55.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sql server 2012

Comment: Remember to store dates as dates!!

Comment: How is this related to "How to find max in a table"?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a subquery:

```
CREATE TABLE #0 (ID varchar(100), department_ID int, mod_date date)

SET DATEFORMAT DMY

INSERT #0 VALUES
('A',33,'12/03/2014'),('A',44,'23/04/2015'),('A',55,'20/05/2016')
,('B',44,'26/01/2014'),('B',33,'24/02/2015'),('B',12,'24/12/2015')
,('B',55,'12/02/2016'),('C',13,'22/05/2014'),('C',14,'01/05/2015')
,('C',55,'02/07/2016'),('C',14,'03/08/2016'),('C',55,'05/10/2016');

SELECT DISTINCT latest.ID
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, mod_date = MAX(mod_date)
    FROM #0
    GROUP BY ID
) maximum
JOIN #0 latest
    ON latest.ID = maximum.ID
    AND latest.mod_date = maximum.mod_date
JOIN #0 older
    ON older.ID = latest.ID
    AND older.mod_date < latest.mod_date
    AND (older.department_ID <> latest.department_ID OR older.department_ID IS NULL)
WHERE latest.department_ID = 55
    AND older.mod_date > '2015-10-12'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.. can we add something to this query such that it will give the last trasition as well. I mean for

Comment: for A 44 23/04/2015

Comment: For A I should get two records with dept id 44 and 55 and for B also same. Sorry for multiple comments that was by mistake.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have replaced my answer with a new one that fixes these issues.

Answer (score 1):

If understood correctly then you may looking for this script

```
SELECT ID
FROM TableName
WHERE department_ID = 55 AND mod_date > '<your_date>'
GROUP BY ID
Having COUNT(department_ID) = 1
```

Comment: can i get last transition as well. I mean for A ID i need two records with dept id 55 and 44 and same for B ID as well

Comment: and I do not have mod_date. That should be max of them group by item id

Comment: Not sure about your business requirement but if you r looking for two department then you can use IN clause `department_ID IN (55,44)`

Comment: for given example the second dep id is 44 but for all other ID it won't be same.. so can not use in clause

Answer (score 0):

maybe this ?

```
declare @temp table (id varchar(1), department_id int, mod_Date date)

insert into @temp values ('A', 33, '20140312')
insert into @temp values ('A', 44, '20150423')
insert into @temp values ('A', 55, '20160520')
insert into @temp values ('B', 44, '20140126')
insert into @temp values ('B', 33, '20150224')
insert into @temp values ('B', 12, '20151224')
insert into @temp values ('B', 55, '20160212')
insert into @temp values ('C', 13, '20140522')
insert into @temp values ('C', 14, '20150501')
insert into @temp values ('C', 55, '20160702')
insert into @temp values ('C', 14, '20160803')
insert into @temp values ('C', 55, '20161005')

select id, max(mod_Date) as lastchanged
from   @temp
where  department_id = 55 
and    mod_date > '20151012'
group by id
having count(department_id) = 1
```

it returns :

```
id  lastchanged 
A   2016-05-20  
B   2016-02-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort by date:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mod_date > '2015/10/12' AND 
department_ID=55 ORDER BY mod_date DESC Limit 1;
```

Sort by ID:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mod_date > '2015/10/12' AND 
department_ID=55 ORDER BY ID Limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) twice. Adding the following two columns to your data:

```
SELECT  ID,
        Department_ID,
        mod_date,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY mod_date DESC),
        RowNum2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Department_ID ORDER BY mod_date)
FROM    #T
WHERE   mod_Date > '20151012';
```

gives

```
ID  Department_ID   mod_date    RowNum  RowNum2
--------------------------------------------------
A   55              2016-05-20  1       1
B   12              2015-12-24  2       1
B   55              2016-02-12  1       1
C   14              2016-08-03  2       1
C   55              2016-07-02  3       1
C   55              2016-10-05  1       2
```

Since you are only interested in where the current department ID is 55, you need to filter for `RowNum = 1 AND Department_ID = 55`, which leaves:

```
ID  Department_ID   mod_date    RowNum  RowNum2
--------------------------------------------------
A   55              2016-05-20  1       1
B   55              2016-02-12  1       1
C   55              2016-10-05  1       2
```

Note that `RowNum2` for `ID = C` is 2, because this is the second time in the period that C has been 55, you are only interested in where the ID hasn't previously been changed to 55, so you need a further predicate of `RowNum2 = 1` giving a final query of:

```
SELECT  ID,
        Department_ID,
        mod_date
FROM    (   SELECT  ID,
                    Department_ID,
                    mod_date,
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY mod_date DESC),
                    RowNum2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Department_ID ORDER BY mod_date)
            FROM    #T
            WHERE   mod_Date > '20151012'
        ) AS t
WHERE   Department_ID = 55
AND     RowNum = 1      -- CURRENT RECORD   
AND     RowNum2 = 1;    -- FIRST TIME ID HAS BEEN THIS DEPARTMENT
```

**FULL WORKING DEMO**

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID CHAR(1), Department_ID INT, mod_date DATE);
INSERT #T
VALUES
    ('A', 33, '20140312'),
    ('A', 44, '20150423'),
    ('A', 55, '20160520'),
    ('B', 44, '20140126'),
    ('B', 33, '20150224'),
    ('B', 12, '20151224'),
    ('B', 55, '20160212'),
    ('C', 13, '20140522'),
    ('C', 14, '20150501'),
    ('C', 55, '20160702'),
    ('C', 14, '20160803'),
    ('C', 55, '20161005');

SELECT  ID,
        Department_ID,
        mod_date
FROM    (   SELECT  ID,
                    Department_ID,
                    mod_date,
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY mod_date DESC),
                    RowNum2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Department_ID ORDER BY mod_date)
            FROM    #T
            WHERE   mod_Date > '20151012'
        ) AS t
WHERE   Department_ID = 55
AND     RowNum = 1      -- CURRENT RECORD   
AND     RowNum2 = 1;    -- FIRST TIME ID HAS BEEN THIS DEPARTMENT
```

**RESULTS**

```
ID  Department_ID   mod_date
----------------------------------
A   55              2016-05-20
B   55              2016-02-12
```